# How to pause execution between threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm learning thread synchronization and this is the demo to show how to lock critical data when a thread is executing:

http://ideone.com/7Do0l
(To run this code, compile it with the `-pthread` parameter in Linux/MacOS environment)

The program works as expected, but the `sleep()` function doesn't pause the execution between threads. My idea is to have one thread do the calculation at a time, then 1 second later another thread comes into play. Here is the code segment I'm fighting with:

```
while(1) {
        //sleep(1);     //(1) (Sleep for one second)
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        //sleep(1);     //(2)
                printf("Thread #%d is doing math. %d + 1 = %d.\n", (int) id, s, s+1);
                s++;
        //sleep(1);     //(3)
        sem_post(&mutex);
        //sleep(1);     //(4)
}
```

There are four positions I have tried to put the `sleep()` in. (1) and (4) result in no pauses between single threads but between two bunches of ten threads. (2) and (3) result in one thread gets executed repeatedly for very long time before another gets called.

Is there a remedy to this?

**Update**

There is a trick to make the program produce the result: generating the sleeping time randomly for each thread, but it's not consistent since two random numbers could be the same by accident.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is the behavior you would expect?

Comment: Should be like:

`Thread #1 is doing math. 1 + 1 = 2.`

(Then 1 second later:)

`Thread #2 is doing math. 2 + 1 = 3.`
(And so on)

Comment: Am I the only one noticing that people here are referencing 1 millisecond as 1 second and in answer below 100 milliseconds as 1 second.

Comment: Don't call a semaphore mutex.

Comment: @Abhineet the `sleep()` function in Linux is in seconds, while the equivalent `Sleep()` (uppercase S) in Windows is in milliseconds.

Comment: @JensGustedt I don't see why. A name is a name, and in this case the semaphore `mutex` serves the same purpose as does "that `mutex`".

Comment: @crazyfffan: Oh..O...thanks for that. I never knew that and even I haven't paid attention to small " s ". My concept here was a typical example of generating blunderous bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found that the only way to produce the desired output is the one I mentioned in the **Update** part. That is, instead of hard coded the sleep timer, just give each thread a random number:

```
    // Sleep time in microseconds.
    int st = rand() % 500000;
    usleep(st);
```

And actually I have been over-worrying about two threads doing the same thing at once. Even though the two adjacent random timers could be accidentally the same, two threads never get executed on the same core of the CPU at the same time, in case the CPU is of multiple cores, no two instructions can modify the same memory content concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the 3rd position, since you want a one second delay between `printf` messages.

If you want to make sure that all threads are initialized before any of them can enter into the critical section, modify the `main` function of the linked code to this

```
int main() {
    pthread_t thread[10];

    int i;
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    for (i = 0; i<10; ++i)
            pthread_create(&(thread[i]), NULL, job, (void*) i);
    sem_post(&mutex);
    sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: I tried that many times, (2) and (3) result in the same behaviour: One thread getting executed repeatedly.

Comment: So what output do you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the code, I've just tried but it works in exactly the same way. You'll see the whole bunch of ten threads get executed at the same time, then a pause, then another bunch of ten threads....

As for the expected output, I have made it clear twice above...

Comment: Putting it in the 3rd position produces the output you described:

`Thread #1 is doing math. 1 + 1 = 2.`, (1s delay), `Thread #2 is doing math. 2 + 1 = 3.`, (1s delay), `Thread #3 is doing math. 3 + 1 = 4.` etc.

Comment: Here is the result produced by my computer, using Linux, with the`main()` function replaced by yours and the `sleep()` function in the 3rd place:

`Thread #1 is doing math. 0 + 1 = 1.
Thread #1 is doing math. 1 + 1 = 2.
Thread #1 is doing math. 2 + 1 = 3.
Thread #1 is doing math. 3 + 1 = 4.`

And so on...

My previous comment was wrong: in the (2) and (3) position, the `sleep()` results in one thread getting executed repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really the kind of problem threads are designed to solve.  You'd have to have a separate semaphore for each thread, have one thread loop through those, calling sem_post on a different one each second, and the rest just calling sem_wait.  May as well just use the one thread.

Comment: I believe there is a solution because this small program is a prototype of what I have to do in my next assignment. I have to somehow manage to get hundreds of similar threads executing their part in turn using only several semaphores to control.